# Java program options parsing using picocli does not work in Spinnaker Run Job stage

Tags: java, gradle, spinnaker, picocli

I run my java main program with args using gradle application plugin's run task. The program uses picocli to parse command line args. This works fine when run in my Dev environment using following command:

```
./gradlew  run --args="-ahttp://foo.com/bar -dmydeviceid"
```

It also runs fine when I ssh into a docker container for my apps docker image.

However, if I run the same Gradle run task in Spinnaker pipeline Run Job stage with same docker image it does not work. Log statements show that arguments are received by program correctly but are not processed by picocli. I am guessing it is because the code generator for picocli is not running in the Run Job of Spinnaker pipeline for some reason.

Any suggestions how to fix this.

Comment: I’m glad you found a workaround. If you’re still interested in investigating the underlying cause I’d be happy to help. Can you share the log statements you mentioned that show args are received by the program but not processed by picocli? Also, did you have a chance to run with the `-Dpicocli.trace=DEBUG` system property?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround. Instead of running the program using 'gradle run', I created a shellscript that uses the distribution tar for the program produced by gradle application plugin.

Here is what the script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Build application tar
gradle -i distTar

tar -xvf ./build/distributions/apk-deployer-cli.tar

./apk-deployer-cli/bin/apk-deployer-cli -a $APK_URL -d $DEVICE_ID
```

Then in spinnaker stage config I set the $APK_URL and $DEVICE_ID as part of the env vars for the stage as follows:

```
      "envVars": [
        {
          "name": "APK_URL",
          "value": "${parameters[\"APK_URL\"]}"
        },
        {
          "name": "DEVICE_ID",
          "value": "${parameters[\"DEVICE_ID\"]}"
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

After facing the same issue while trying to debug a minor change to my code. I was faced with the same issue.

Do replace double quotes with single quotes for the args parameter.

`./gradlew  run --args='-a="http://example.com/bar" -d="mydeviceid"'`

I found this while debugging my app using Fleet.

- When using double quotes, gradle returns a single string in the `String...` (a stream of a single string).
- When using single quotes, gradle properly passes multiple strings in the `String...`.

Now to confuse things even more, when used in the `run.json` file used by Fleet, do not use any single quote after the equals as seen below.

Hopefully, this will help others facing this issue.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "gradle",
            "name": "execute picocli app",
            "tasks": [
                "clean",
                "installDist",
                "run"
            ],
            "args": [
                "--info",
                "--args=--test -P --servername=\"bogus.local\"",
                "-Dpicocli.trace=DEBUG"
            ]
        }        
    ]
}
```